# EnableTwitter and EnableFacebook cannot be resolved

Tags: java, facebook, spring, api, twitter

I am trying connect my current spring project with Twitter and Facebook, and for this I am following the instructions from this two posts:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/

And so, I add this two classes to my project:

**TwitterConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.social.UserIdSource;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.config.annotation.EnableTwitter;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository;

@EnableTwitter(appId="...", appSecret="...")
@EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository
public class TwitterConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserIdSource userIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                return "testuser";
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

}
```

**FacebookConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.social.UserIdSource;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.config.annotation.EnableFacebook;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository;

@EnableFacebook(appId="...", appSecret="...")
@EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository
public class FacebookConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserIdSource userIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                return "testuser";
            }
        };
    }

}
```

and add this lines in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but despite this all, the annotations EnableTwitter, EnableFacebook and EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository canoot be resolved.

Anyone can say what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@EnableTwitter` and similar no longer exists.

The generic `@EnableSocial` is there now. And `SocialConfigurer` is for you to implement.

Right, those guildes should be updated and it is on our radar.

More info you can find from the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Thank you for pointing out it one moretime.